# MySQL: Creating table with two foreign keys fails with "Duplicate key name" error

Tags: mysql, sql

While trying to create a new table, MySQL is giving me an error I cannot explain.

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE WarehouseMovements (
    time        DATETIME           NOT NULL,
    product1    INT                NOT NULL,
    product2    INT                NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY WarehouseMovements(product1) REFERENCES Products(id),
    FOREIGN KEY WarehouseMovements(product2) REFERENCES Products(id)
);
```

This fails with `ERROR 1061 (42000): Duplicate key name 'WarehouseMovements'`. If I remove the foreign key constraints this succeeds, but I want to make sure product1 and product2 are actually pointing to somewhere.

Default engine is InnoDB.

What's wrong with the query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try making the FK names distinct:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE WarehouseMovements (
    time        DATETIME           NOT NULL,
    product1    INT                NOT NULL,
    product2    INT                NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY IX_WarehouseMovements_product1(product1) REFERENCES Products(id),
    FOREIGN KEY IX_WarehouseMovements_product2(product2) REFERENCES Products(id)
);
```

UPDATE

That's an index or FK name, not a table name.  See [create-table-foreign-keys documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
[index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
```

Which says

> index_name represents a foreign key ID. If given, this is ignored if
>   an index for the foreign key is defined explicitly. Otherwise, if
>   MySQL creates an index for the foreign key, it uses index_name for the
>   index name.

Comment: I was under the impression I was supposed to put the table name before the parentheses... Huh. Thanks! This worked.

Comment: @GiorgosBitzes I added a reference where the syntax is described.  There are a couple way to do this.  You'll also see FK_ name prefixes.

Answer (score 6):

you must to add constraint with different names to FK

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE WarehouseMovements (
    time DATETIME NOT NULL,
    product1 INT NOT NULL,
    product2 INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_product_1 FOREIGN KEY (product1) REFERENCES Products (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_product_2 FOREIGN KEY (product2) REFERENCES Products (id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `cca_orders` 
ADD  CONSTRAINT `item_id` 
FOREIGN KEY (`item_id`) 
REFERENCES `joshi_textile_db`.`cca_items_master`(`id`) 
ON DELETE RESTRICT 
ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```