# Liquibase primary key is created twice on H2

Tags: mysql, hibernate, h2, liquibase

At start problem is only with H2 database. On other database (MySQL) it works just fine without problems.

Configuration generated by (jHipster):

profile: *dev*

```
spring:
profiles:
    active: dev
datasource:
    dataSourceClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://******.net.net:3306/*****_pandemicd?autoReconnect=true
    databaseName: ****************
    serverName: ******.net
    username: ****************
    password: ****************
    cachePrepStmts: true
    prepStmtCacheSize: 250
    prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
    useServerPrepStmts: true

jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    database: MYSQL
    openInView: true
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
    properties:
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: true
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: pl.sedzisz.pandemic.config.hazelcast.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
        hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts: true
        hibernate.cache.hazelcast.use_lite_member: true
```

profile: *test* (in memory)

```
spring:
datasource:
    dataSourceClassName: org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:pandemic;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4
    databaseName:
    serverName:
    username:
    password:

jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    database: H2
    openInView: true
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
    properties:
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: false
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: false
        hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate
```

Now Liquibase changelog:

```
<changeSet author="newbie" id="1449941926339-1">
    <createTable tableName="ENUM_DESCENT">
        <column name="descent_of_disease" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="newbie" id="1449941926339-2">
    <loadData encoding="UTF-8"
              file="config/liquibase/descent_of_disease.csv"
              separator=";"
              tableName="ENUM_DESCENT"/>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="newbie" id="1449941926339-3">
    <createTable tableName="DISEASE_DESCENTS">
        <column name="disease_id" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="descent_descent_of_disease" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="newbie" id="1449941926339-4">
    <addPrimaryKey columnNames="disease_id, descent_descent_of_disease"
                   constraintName="PRIMARY"
                   tableName="DISEASE_DESCENTS"/>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="newbie" id="1449941926339-5">
    <addPrimaryKey columnNames="descent_of_disease"
                   constraintName="PRIMARY"
                   tableName="ENUM_DESCENT"/>
</changeSet>
```

And sample of log:

```
 [DEBUG] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-4::newbie: Executing EXECUTE database command: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.DISEASE_DESCENTS ADD CONSTRAINT "PRIMARY" PRIMARY KEY (disease_id, descent_descent_of_disease)
 [INFO] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-4::newbie: Primary key added to DISEASE_DESCENTS (disease_id, descent_descent_of_disease)
 [INFO] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-4::newbie: ChangeSet config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-4::newbie ran successfully in 1ms
 [DEBUG] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-4::newbie: Computed checksum for addPrimaryKey:[
columnNames="disease_id, descent_descent_of_disease"
constraintName="PRIMARY"
tableName="DISEASE_DESCENTS"
 ] as eb8eba06bfcf2a30a029b8e49ea7d549
 [DEBUG] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-4::newbie: Computed checksum for 7:eb8eba06bfcf2a30a029b8e49ea7d549: as 212a7c01d41bbcb1f9772a2d93161529
 [DEBUG] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-4::newbie: Executing EXECUTE database command: INSERT INTO PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, LIQUIBASE) VALUES ('1449941926339-4', 'newbie', 'config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml', NOW(), 6, '7:212a7c01d41bbcb1f9772a2d93161529', 'addPrimaryKey', '', 'EXECUTED', '3.3.2')
 [DEBUG] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-4::newbie: Computed checksum for addPrimaryKey:[
columnNames="disease_id, descent_descent_of_disease"
constraintName="PRIMARY"
tableName="DISEASE_DESCENTS"
 ] as eb8eba06bfcf2a30a029b8e49ea7d549
 [DEBUG] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-4::newbie: Computed checksum for 7:eb8eba06bfcf2a30a029b8e49ea7d549: as 212a7c01d41bbcb1f9772a2d93161529
 [DEBUG] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-5::newbie: Running Changeset:config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-5::newbie
 [DEBUG] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-5::newbie: Changeset config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-5::newbie
 [DEBUG] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-5::newbie: Reading ChangeSet: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-5::newbie
 [DEBUG] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-5::newbie: Executing Statement: liquibase.statement.core.AddPrimaryKeyStatement@7334b84d
 [DEBUG] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-5::newbie: Executing EXECUTE database command: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.ENUM_DESCENT ADD CONSTRAINT "PRIMARY" PRIMARY KEY (descent_of_disease)
 [ERROR] liquibase - classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml: config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-5::newbie: Change Set config/liquibase/changelog/20151115220815_added_entity_Descent.xml::1449941926339-5::newbie failed.  Error: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Ograniczenie "PRIMARY" już istnieje
 Constraint "PRIMARY" already exists; SQL statement: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.ENUM_DESCENT ADD CONSTRAINT "PRIMARY" PRIMARY KEY (descent_of_disease) [90045-187]
 liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Ograniczenie "PRIMARY" już istnieje
 Constraint "PRIMARY" already exists; SQL statement: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.ENUM_DESCENT ADD CONSTRAINT "PRIMARY" PRIMARY KEY (descent_of_disease) [90045-187] at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na] at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na] at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1227) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1210) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:550) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:43) [liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:73) [liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:200) [liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:353) [liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:317) [liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:444) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) [spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
```

Workaround:

```
<changeSet author="newbie" id="1449941926339-4">
    <addPrimaryKey columnNames="disease_id, descent_descent_of_disease"
                   constraintName="PRIMARY_DISEASE_DESCENTS"
                   tableName="DISEASE_DESCENTS"/>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="newbie" id="1449941926339-5">
    <addPrimaryKey columnNames="descent_of_disease"
                   constraintName="PRIMARY_ENUM_DESCENT"
                   tableName="ENUM_DESCENT"/>
</changeSet>
```

[MySQL: Creating table with two foreign keys fails with “Duplicate key name” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699936/mysql-creating-table-with-two-foreign-keys-fails-with-duplicate-key-name-erro)

Comment: Please do not add tags to your title. There is no need to add "[solved]" to your title.

Comment: You've already marked an answer below as accepted. This marks the question as solved already.

Comment: a few seconds ago I got advice that I should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add the primary keys after the table creation liquibase will use an `ALTER TABLE... ADD CONSTRAINT...`. And you can not have multiple constraints with the same name. So H2 reports an error.

You have already found a workaround.

Maybe another way would be to add your primary key definitions to the create table statement:

```
<changeSet author="newbie" id="1449941926339-1">
    <createTable tableName="ENUM_DESCENT">
        <column name="descent_of_disease" type="VARCHAR(255)">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Then the primary key definition will be handled in the `CREATE TABLE...` statement.

(BTW: This does not happen on mySQL because mySQL is able to use `PRIMARY KEY` on the `ALTER TABLE...` statement. So with a mySQL DB liquibase will translate your `addPrimaryKey` changeset to something like `ALTER TABLE... ADD PRIMARY KEY...`)

Comment: Thank You! or simpler `<constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>`